# Wordpress htaccess rewrite rules with url parameter

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a php script on the root of the server that people link to it like this:

```
http://mywebsite.com/test.php?id=123
```

I have created a new WordPress website for a client and created a custom post type that accepts url parameters and works similarly to the old script when accessed at:

```
http://mywebsite.com/test/?id=123
```

It is also requested that user is always redirected to http, even if he comes from a https link. I've added my rewrite rules after WordPress rules in htaccess. These are my rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} test.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ test.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

First one is to always redirect to http and second to rewrite and retain parameter.
It partially works, if I access:

```
https://mywebsite.com/test.php?id=123
```

it takes me to:

```
http://mywebsite.com/test/?id=123
```

but no rewrite if I access:

```
http://mywebsite.com/test.php?id=123
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

This meets requirements, it also handles www or not. Works at the end of .htaccess so it doesn't conflict Wordpress rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mywebsite\.com$
RewriteRule ^test\.php$ "http\:\/\/mywebsite\.com\/test\/" [R=301,L]
```